# Pass parameters through function with .get() python

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
    cmd = raw_input("> ")
    if cmd[0] == "/":
        if " " in cmd:
            cmd = cmd.split(" ")
            {
            '/help':  help,
            '/cf':  cf(f = cmd[1]),
            '/rf':  rf(f = cmd[1]),
            '/md':  md(f = cmd[1]), 
            '/rd':  rd(f = cmd[1]), 
            '/dir': dir(f = cmd[1]), 
            '/tree': tree(f = cmd[1]), 
            '/date': date, 
            '/time': time_, 
            '/clear': clear,
            '/echo': echo(f = cmd[1]),   
            }.get(cmd[0])()
```

For some reason, if I call, say, /md, it runs it as if I called /cf, can anyone offer any insight?

My whole code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ukwY6LfV

Comment: Can you provide more information, are you using the code posted here or the code from pastebin? Paste all the code here then provide couple testing scenarios where your code is not returning the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking more deeply into your code, I can tell you that your structure looks odd... Looking at the second line in your dict, `'/cf':  cf(f = cmd[1]),` you're calling the func cf() there, and then potentially calling it again at the end with the `}.get(cmd[0])()` at the end. I see that you're trying to set f as the parameter, too. But I don't think you want to be calling the func in the first instance. Rather you just want the "pointer" to the func, the func name.
Since you're trying to pass an arg, I think the lambda statement is what you want. So, try changing:

```
'/cf':  cf(f = cmd[1]),
```

to

```
'/cf':  lambda p=cmd[1]: cf(f = p),
```

and see if that does the trick.  With the lambda call, you're not actually calling the cf() func, but rather you're creating a new, nameless function that IS going to later call the cf() func with the desired parameter, if invoked.

Your lines for /date, /time, and /clear should be okay, but you will need to change all the other lines inside your "dict" statement to use the lambda call.